# Azure Defender and specific App Services

Tags: azure, azure-app-services

I'm reading the documentation for Azure Defender (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/security-center/azure-defender) and this suggests that the only way to enable Azure Defender for App Service is through enabling for the subscription which would enable for all App Services which make use of the following App Service Plans; Basic, Standard, Premium, Isolated, or Linux.

Azure Defender for SQL and Azure Defender for Storage seem to be more granular and allow enabling on specific resources. Is there any way to only enable for specific App Services (or specific App Service Plans and the derived App Services)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the default is that when you turn on Azure Defender for a service it is for all services in that subscription. SQL and Storage are the exception in that they allow some configuration changes to exclude resources, pretty much all the other resource types do not.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sam. It is what I thought, I was asking out of hope more than expectation.